# Use jscolor picker to change div radial-gradient color

Tags: javascript, jscolor

I have this div with an image inside. How can I make the jscolor picker change one color value of the radial-gradient in that div?

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" style="background: radial-gradient(1300px circle at 50% 50%, #090b3c, #000000);">
 <img src="../usrimages/cc_270719195202.png" border="0" class="border"><br>
</div>

<!-- And I'm using jscolor as colorpicker: -->

<script>
function update(jscolor) {
    // 'jscolor' instance can be used as a string
    document.getElementById('rect').style.backgroundColor = '#' + jscolor
}
</script>

<input name="clr1" class="jscolor {onFineChange:'update(this)'}">

<!-- Right now it's changing the color to a rectangle: -->

<p id="rect" style="border:1px solid gray; width:161px; height:100px;">
```

I've tried stuff like this:

```
document.getElementById('gradientbg').style.backgroundColor = 'radial-gradient(1300px circle at 50% 50%, #FF0000, #000000)';
```

and this:

```
document.getElementById('gradientbg').style.background = 'radial-gradient(1300px circle at 50% 50%, #FF0000, #000000)';
```

and this:

```
document.getElementById('gradientbg').style.backgroundImage = 'radial-gradient(1300px circle at 50% 50%, #FF0000, #000000)';
```

Comment: You have to set `backgroundImage`.  The code you posted does not include an "id" attribute on the `<div>` you want to update.

Comment: <script>document.getElementById('gradientbg').style.backgroundImage = 'radial-gradient(1300px circle at 50% 50%, #FF0000, #000000)';
</script>

<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" id="gradientbg"></div>

I've tried this direct color change but nothing. How do I set "backgroundImage"?

Please help me understnad, I'm noob and learning.

Comment: I just needed to move the script after the div, it's working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the `.style.backgroundImage` to your new gradient should work:

```js
function changeColor(ev) {
    // 'jscolor' instance can be used as a string
    document.querySelector('.rect').style.backgroundImage = 'radial-gradient(100px circle at 50% 50%, ' + ev.target.value + ', #000000)';

}

document.querySelector("input").onchange = changeColor;
```

```css
.rect { height: 50px; margin-bottom: 12px; }
```

```html
<div class="rect" style="background: radial-gradient(100px circle at 50% 50%, #ff0000, #000000);"></div>
<input type="color" value="#ff0000">
```